# List with list dividers in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having trouble creating a list with list dividers in between to categories the items.
The dividers should be titled the month name and the items should have items posted in that month.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

```
- August
  - list item 1
  - list item 2
- September
  - list item 3
  - list item 4
  - list item 5
```

Each list item has the date timestamp where I extract the month from.

**What I've tried**

```
export class PostItemService {
  groupedItems = [];

  // second item is the date timestamp
  items: item[] = [
    new item('cool title', 1503469292, 'some cool text'),
    new item('second title', 1503469292, 'some cool text'),
    new item('third title', 1503469292, 'some cool text'),
  ];

  splitOnMonth() {

    const items = this.items;
    const groupedItem = [];

    // extract the month number
    function convertTimeStamp(timestamp) {
        const date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
        const monthNumber = date.getMonth() + 1;

        return monthNumber;
    }

   items.forEach((value, index) => {

      const myMonth = convertTimeStamp(value.date);

      // Actually, I don't now where to go from here

   });

  } // splitOnMonth()

}
```

I've tried a lot more things, but I don't think it's necessary adding it here. The main thing is; I don't know where to go from here.

I hope somebody have encountered and solved the same problem or can help me with this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't really see in the code that you made an attempt at what you're describing at all? You've just declared an array and you have some logic for parsing the month...

Comment: I have made multiple attempt, but I just keep commeting them out because they don't work. I have tried using .map() methods, I have tried adding a temp array and populating that array. I can add all these attempts in this code block, but I think it will overcloud the question.

I can still provide them, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a map of month objects identified by their month number, with 2 properties in each object, the name, and an array containing all the items from that month. Iterate through all your items to find their month then push them into the empty array for the corresponding month (creating the object if it doesn't already exist), then in your template, iterate through the month array and display items only if they have 1 or more subitems, and if they have subitems, iterate through that array.

UPDATE - Plunkr link - https://plnkr.co/edit/w6EaEe9yoVMr7OKExXwc?p=preview

```
 export class PostItemService {

   monthMap : { [index : number] : { monthName: string, items: item[] }};
   monthArray: any[] = [];

   items: item[] = [
      new item('cool title', 1503469292, 'some cool text'),
      new item('second title', 1503469292, 'some cool text'),
      new item('third title', 1503469292, 'some cool text'),
   ];

   constructor() {
       this.monthMap = {  
           1: { monthName: 'January', items: [] },
           2: { monthName: 'February', items: [] },
           3: { monthName: 'March', items: [] },
              // ... and so on ... dont want to type it all
              // you could build this iteratively if you just had a 12 length array of the string names, but its easier to show it explicitly for the example
              // ideally you could just create an empty map and only add a month object if it ends up with items, that would prevent you from having to check lengths later.
       };

       this.splitOnMonth();
   }

   splitOnMonth() {

     // extract the month number
     var convertTimeStamp = (timestamp)=> {
         const date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
         const monthNumber = date.getMonth() + 1;
         return monthNumber;
     }

     items.forEach((value, index)=>{

          const myMonth = convertTimeStamp(value.date);

          this.monthMap[myMonth].items.push(value);
     });

    // after that method completes, you can convert your month map to an array, only adding the numbered objects to the array if they have items in their items array  

     for (let prop in monthMap) {
        if (this.monthMap[prop].items.length > 0) {
            this.monthArray.push(this.monthMap[prop]);
        }
     }

     // now you have an array you can iterate through in the template of a component somewhere
  }  

}
```

In some component's template...

```
<ul class="month-groups">
   <li *ngFor="let month of this.monthArray">
       {{ month.monthName }} 
        <ul class="month-items">
            <li *ngFor="let item of month.items">
                 {{ item.value }} // or whatever info from items you need to show 
             </li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

That should do it, you'd just probably want to style the different ul's properly, and maybe add extra margin-left to the nested ones.

NOTE -  you were missing a fat arrow in your forEach function. Also - in angular you typically want to avoid doing much in the constructor of components, but with services its fine because they don't have an associated view to render. I instantiated the month map in the constructor just to separate it from my typed declaration above and make it clearer. If this is a service you'd probably wouldn't be calling the splitMonth() method from the constructor, but if you just want to test it ,that's an easy way to do it.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. Nice solution.

Comment: Also i dont really understand date timestamps well so i just changed numbers in them at random to get the months to change...

Comment: apparently i don't know how to share plunker links...    does this work for you?  

https://plnkr.co/edit/w6EaEe9yoVMr7OKExXwc?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating a Pipe for this.

Look at this snippet:

```
    @Pipe({
      name: 'ItemsFilterPipe',
      pure: false
    })
    export class ItemsFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(items: Item[]): FilteredItem[] {
        // Here you can do whatever you want with your data like creating a new object with timestamp as key and the item as value
      }
    }
```

and you can use it as followed:

```
*ngFor="let item of items | ItemsFilterPipe"
```

in this ngFor, item contains {"1503469292": Item[]}

Comment: OP - this is potentially a better and much cleaner solution if all you need to do is display the data like that , and you don't actually need to organize it by month